# from pandasgui import show gives error and will not load

Tags: python, pandasgui

I am trying to use Pandasgui with the below code

```
import os
import pandas as PD
from pandasgui import show
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]})
show(df)
```

but it gives me the error

> cannot import name 'show' from partially initialized module 'pandasgui'

Please guide me in solving this issue